# Create a Year Dropdown Box FormBuilder In Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, date, formbuilder

I am trying to create a db that has a year attribute but I am having some difficulty. I created the scaffold and tryied to modify the _form.html.erb with this code:

```
<%= f.date_select :year, :start_year=>2000, :end_year=>Time.now.year %>
```

Tried to run the rails server and gave me this error:

```
1 error(s) on assignment of multiparameter attributes
```

I realized that I only wanted the year and not the day or month. Is there a way to do that? I tried :discard_month=>true but that just hides it, but still storing it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do something like:

```
<%= f.date_select :year, :order => [:year], :start_year => 2000, :end_year => Time.now.year, :prompt => {:year => "Select year"} %>
```

Because your `year` field is an `int` and not a `datetime`:

```
<%= f.select :year, (2000..Time.now.year).to_a, :include_blank => {:year => "Select year"} %>
```

Comment: Tried but it doesn't work. my attribute is year:integer. it is still trying to store multiple parameters, just nil now

Comment: Using a date_select, you'll always get a date, so the field in your db should be consistent.

Comment: is there any other option to make a dropdown box for year other than date_select say from 1900-2012?

Comment: Thanks. what does the ".to_a" do?

Comment: it creates an Array from the range.

Comment: If you want to switch the order you can do .to_a.reverse

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is [select_year](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/select_year)

e.g.,

`select_year(Date.current, start_year: 2015, end_year: Date.current.year)`